# replacement for document.all.sort.length

Tags: javascript, sorting, cross-browser

```
function ShowSortArrows() {
            for ( var i = 0; i < document.all.sort.length; i++ ) {
                document.all.sort[i].style.display = "none";
                document.all.sort[i].style.visibility = "";
            }
            if (iSortByColumn!=1) {
                if (strSortType=="ASC") {
                    document.all.sort[(iSortByColumn*2)-4].style.display="inline";
                } else {
                    document.all.sort[(iSortByColumn*2)-3].style.display="inline";
                }
            }
        }
```

This is not supported in new browsers, so I need replacement.

Thanks,
Ilija

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you showed `sort` can be 2 things.

1. a `<form>` with the name or id `sort`
2. a collection of form elements named `sort`

The solutions for these situations are:

**(1)**

```
var sort = document.getElementById("sort");
var elements = sort.getElementsByTagName("input");
```

**(2)**

```
var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var elements = [];
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  if (input[i].name === "sort") {
     elements.push(input[i]);
  }
}
```

Then the `elements` array will contain what you would get with the old-fashioned `document.all.sort`

Answer (score 0):

It basically depends on what `sort` is (no HTML shown). It's not a valid HTML tag and there appear to be more than one per page so I'll assume it's a class name :-?

```
for ( var i=0, len=document.getElementsByClassName("sort").length; i<len; i++) {
}
```

Comment: It's quite possible that `document.all.sort` refers to a form named "sort", in which case `document.all.sort[i]` refers to the form's inputs. In any case, we need to see the original HTML so we can help you.